# Turn off screen from inside app in windows phone 7

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Is there way to turn off the screen from within the app in windows phone 7?

I went through the documentation but could not find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no possibly way to do this. The only thing you can do (if you want to make the screen black) is remove all the controls in the page or plop a black rectangle over everything. You cant mess with the WP7 OS API like that

Answer (score 4):

No, you cant turn off the screen from your application.
Microsoft certification will not allow application to do so, even though if your able to do with some hacks