# Does windows phone allow application to turn off/on the screen?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

As I mentioned in the title, I plan to write an **sensor-based application** for windows phone platform, but I don't know if windows phone allow application (using some codes) to turn off/on the screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341134/turn-off-screen-from-inside-app-in-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft certification will not allow application to do so, even though if your able to do with some hacks. You cant turn off the screen from your application. This type of app cannot be made for Windows Phone, the API's do not exist, and if someone found a workaround it would be removed from the store. Unfortunately non of the developers have developed such app for windows. One app is available on Windows phone store `One Touch Lockscreen`, Find [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/one-touch-lockscreen/a3b1220b-1f9a-4bf0-93bc-21ed02792279)

Comment: I really appreciate for your help! I'll try to contact with the developer of the app that you suggested, if I'm lucky, I maybe get support from them. Again, thanks alot.

Comment: @ManhNguyenVan If this answer is helpful for this question then vote up and accept the answer, Other people those who are finding info related to this question they will get the answer here.

Comment: @CharanGhate I like answers saying `no, you can't; even if you can, you shouldn't` and giving concrete reasons.