# How to turn the screen off in windows phone?

Tags: c#, screen, win-universal-app

I've searched for it ,but I can't find the answer.

what I found is that how to keep the screen alive.

I wanna try to write the uwp that

when I click a button ,the screen will be turned off.

is there any function?

thank for any reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. You cannot turn off the screen from your app.

Comment: Excuse me. I have a question. There is the uwp called Linphone. When you are talking,the screen is off.  does it do some in special way?. or there is other way can  look like the screen off.

Comment: @闕裕柏:- You need to ask a separate question for that!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will not allow application to do so. The API won't support this. Even if you did it with some hacks such app will be removed from store.

Comment: Excuse me. I have a question. There is the uwp called Linphone. When you are talking,the screen is off.  does it do some in special way?. or there is other way can  look like the screen off.

Answer (score 0):

There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228258/does-windows-phone-allow-application-to-turn-off-on-the-screen) about your question in StackOverFlow:

> Microsoft certification will not allow application to do so, even
>   though if your able to do with some hacks. You cant turn off the
>   screen from your application. This type of app cannot be made for
>   Windows Phone, the API's do not exist, and if someone found a
>   workaround it would be removed from the store. Unfortunately non of
>   the developers have developed such app for windows

Comment: Excuse me. I have a question. There is the uwp called Linphone. When you are talking,the screen is off.  does it do some in special way?. or there is other way can  look like the screen off.